# Sun (oracle) Java on new projects

Tags: java, oracle, sun

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there reliable alternatives to Sun's JVM for desktop & enterprise development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194980/are-there-reliable-alternatives-to-suns-jvm-for-desktop-enterprise-development)

I'm considering a large long term Java project.

I'm seeing some negative signs in the Oracle takeover of Sun and concerned that this may affect the viability of using Sun (Oracle) on the project.

Should I consider using another Java implementation base?  If so, what looks good long term?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194980/are-there-reliable-alternatives-to-suns-jvm-for-desktop-enterprise-development

Comment: Another Java implementation?  AFAIK, there is only one Java Programming Language.

Comment: Yes, only one Java language but many Java Virtual Machines implementations and development tools.

Answer (score 5):

I think whatever you think your fears are, they're unfounded.

First, if your long term project is relying on too-be-released software (i.e. stuff that isn't even out yet, like JDK 7, 8, and whatever features they may or may not bring), then you need to re-evaluate that part of your plan.

If you expect to have a reliable Java 6 implementation in the long term, then you probably shouldn't worry.

Java 6 is solid, reliable, and it's not going away. AT A MINIMUM, Oracle, as a company, is going to continue to invest and develop its applications servers and middle ware, all of which rely on Java.

It is in NO ONES interest to "cripple" Java. While you may not get "free" tech support from Oracle, Oracle will continue to provide and maintain freely available for production, and viable JVMs for the platforms they support now (notably x86 and SPARC), and they've already agreed to pick up the JVM for Mac OS.

So, in that sense, I don't see Java 6 suddenly (i.e. next 5 years) going away. Support may be deprecated and maintenance stopped to a point in lieu of J7 or J8. Consider the legs Java 5 still have, and even Java 4 in some places, still today. But I see no foreseeable end of life for Java as a whole.

Is any of this FACT? Do I have public or secret Oracle memo's committing to any of this? No.

I have no crystal balls.

But I don't see the future of Java as cloudy at all. Stirred up a bit, sure, but not cloudy. In the conservative world of corporate IT, stability is greatly treasured. Status Quo A Number One. The only thing that will "hurt Java" is something else entirely, it sure won't be Oracle.

Comment: I thought that IBM has also signed on to help with the OpenJDK project. That should also help with the long term support of Java 6 in the enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

Developing in Java means your work will function across a number of different platforms, so there's no vendor lock-in issues.  Oracle, IBM, and others are also supporting the OpenJDK project, so you can always switch to that if you don't like the terms of the available proprietary implementations.